# Are there any differences between the standing wave diagrams of two non-transposing instruments?

Tags: waves, acoustics

For example, a cello and a flute are both non-transposing instruments. Thus, they both have harmonics at the same frequencies. Will there be any differences in their pressure time graphs then?

Answer (score 1):

In music, the term "transposing instruments" only refers to the notation, not the physics of how the instrument works.

For instruments that produce a sustained sound at constant amplitude, the sound pressure can always be represented (using Fourier analysis) by "harmonics" which are integer multiples of the fundamental frequency. However the amplitude and relative phase of the harmonics depends on the instrument (and also how it is played) so the pressure-time graphs of the sounds are different.

Note that this Fourier analysis tells you *nothing* about the "natural" modes of vibration of the instrument, because the sound is produced by a continuous input of energy and the system is undergoing "forced vibration" not "free vibration."

For example, the sound of organ pipes can be described in this way using Fourier analysis, but the description of the harmonics of "open" and "stopped" pipes you find in elementary physics textbooks is a complete work of fiction if applied to *real* organ pipes, which are *not* simple cylindrical tubes with the ends either fully open or fully closed. The *resonant* frequencies of real organ pipes do *not* follow simple 1:2:3... or 1:3:5... ratios, even approximately.

For instruments that do not produce a sustained sound (piano, guitar, bells, etc). the frequencies of the natural vibration modes of the instrument are *not* usually in simple integer ratios.

Even for "stretched string" instruments like piano and guitar, the frequencies are only *approximately* in the ratio 1:2:3:etc, and the small deviations are important in understanding real instruments, rather than the simple idealized mathematical models of them you learn about in a first course on sound and vibration.

For pitched percussion instruments (bells, xylophone, marimba, timpani, etc) the frequencies of the harmonics are not even approximately in simple integer ratios, and the ratios are different for different instruments.